# How do procedures work with object types in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, object-type

I don't fully understand the purpose of procedures for PL/SQL object types. From reading online, the impression I got was that functions should not modify the data and should only return a value, instead procedures should be used, however it appears that for object types, changes in a procedure don't propagate outside the local context:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TestType FORCE
AS OBJECT
(
    TestValue NUMBER

, CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION TestType
    RETURN SELF AS RESULT

,   MEMBER PROCEDURE IncrementValueAsProcedure

,   MEMBER FUNCTION IncrementValueAsFunction
    RETURN TestType
)
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY TestType
AS
    CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION TestType
    RETURN SELF AS RESULT
  IS
  BEGIN
        SELF.TestValue := 0;
        RETURN;
    END;

    MEMBER PROCEDURE IncrementValueAsProcedure
    IS
        MyType TestType := SELF;
    BEGIN
        MyType.TestValue := TestValue + 1;
    END;

    MEMBER FUNCTION IncrementValueAsFunction
    RETURN TestType
    IS
        MyType TestType := SELF;
    BEGIN
        MyType.TestValue := TestValue + 1;
        RETURN MyType;
    END;
END;
/

DECLARE
    MyTest TestType;
BEGIN
    MyTest := TestType();
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(MyTest.TestValue);
    MyTest.IncrementValueAsProcedure();
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(MyTest.TestValue);
    MyTest := MyTest.IncrementValueAsFunction();
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(MyTest.TestValue);
END;
```

This gives the output:

```
0
0
1
```

So the change in the update procedure hasn't been picked up. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @user7294900 This is specifically in regards to object types, which aren't mentioned in that. My general question is why object types seem to work contrary to the advice in that thread.

Comment: @user7294900 Not a duplicate - that is a generic difference between procedures and functions and this is looking at a specific behaviour/syntax for object member procedures/functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, worked this out.

```
MEMBER PROCEDURE IncrementValueAsProcedure
IS
    MyType TestType := SELF;
BEGIN
    MyType.TestValue := TestValue + 1;
END;
```

This creates a *copy* of the current object and updates it. The following works as expected:

```
MEMBER PROCEDURE IncrementValueAsProcedure
IS
BEGIN
    TestValue := TestValue + 1;
END;
```